# (VBA-Excel) Efficient way to transfer a large range

Tags: vba, excel

I was wondering, which would be more efficient for a transfer of a large range of cells (about 100 000 cells - 10 000 x 10) between workbooks or worksheets:
1. Copying and pasting as values:

```
rng1.Copy
rng2.PasteSpecial xlValues
Application.CutCopyMode=False
```

2. Passing only the values with .Value:

```
rng2.Value = rng1.value
'The ranges will be predefined to be the same size
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: I'd suggest `rng2.Value2 = rng1.value2`

Comment: [range v array](http://excelexperts.com/array-speed-range-vs-array) may help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure your second option is best, but formatting won't be transferred. You may want to consider using `Value2` instead, there is a performance improvement over using `Value`.

```
rng2.Value2 = rng1.value2
```

**Edit 1**

After doing some testing, I'm surprised to see that copy/paste can be faster, about 5 times faster with the testing below, but this is with a mostly empty range. Also, `Value2` reaches an out of memory error sooner. That being said, `Value2` is cleaner code and it doesn't wipe out your clipboard contents, something to think about.

```
Public Declare Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
Sub test()
    Dim r1, r2 As Range
    Dim t As Long

    Set r1 = Sheets("S1").Range("A1:Z100000")
    Set r2 = Sheets("S2").Range("A1:Z100000")

    'Method1
    t = GetTickCount
    r1.Copy
    r2.PasteSpecial xlValues
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - t

    'Method 2
    t = GetTickCount
    r2.Value2 = r1.Value2
    Debug.Print GetTickCount - t

End Sub
```

**Edit 2**

Previous testing was with a mostly empty range. Filling the range with a Table and filing the table with content shows that `Value2` is ~40% faster at handling the full range, but it always handles the full range. I suspect that the difference may be that Copy/Paste has the advantage of being more superficial and thereby realizes a performance gain if empty cells are present.

Comment: I can't say I am surprised, much like the case of find and replace often being the most efficient way of doing most things in word - when it comes to interacting with office apps via vba, the obvious way is rarely the most efficient. Thank god we can now do it all with linq to xml :)

Comment: @NickDewitt Yea, perhaps Copy/Paste can be quicker because it's more superficial.  Further testing shows that it's ~40% slower when the array is entirely filled with equations... btw, just curious, can you see any reason why this answer has been down voted?

Comment: Nah it's more efficient because it's not written in vba, office handles the clipboard a bit differently to other programs anyway - especially when pasting between office apps. I wonder if it's even quicker to just move the underlying xml (I would guess so) - no time to test right now. I don't know why, but I guess it's because you are `pretty sure` instead of `have tested and come up with the answer`

Comment: Thank you for the time spent. I guess I should start using value2 more often.